# Retrofit not returning any response

Tags: android, gson, retrofit

I am trying to use [RetroFit](http://square.github.io/retrofit/) `Synchronus` call to connect and fetch data to one of my APIs.

```
try{            
            RestAdapter restAdapter = new RestAdapter.Builder().setEndpoint(finalUri.toString()).build();
            IGooglePlacesApi iGPlaceApi = restAdapter.create(IGooglePlacesApi.class);
            mGooglePlacesApiResponse googlePlacesObj = iGPlaceApi.getStreams();
            RetrofitError retrofitError;
        } catch (IOException e) {
            serverResponse = e.getMessage();
        } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
            serverResponse = e.getMessage();
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            Log.d("serverResponse:", serverResponse);
        }
```

Which is declared here as:

```
public interface IGooglePlacesApi {
    @GET("/stream/list.json")
    mGooglePlacesApiResponse getStreams();
}
```

Issue is when i call `iGPlaceApi.getStreams();` i dont get a result neither any error. But my code just directly goes to the finally block?

Why this is happening, no result, no catch. How can i correct this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Retrofit wraps all internal exceptions into a RetrofitError exception and throws that.  In your case you're not catching that exception therefore only the finally block is executed.

Try modifying your code this way,

```
try {            
    RestAdapter restAdapter = new RestAdapter.Builder().setEndpoint(finalUri.toString()).build();
    IGooglePlacesApi iGPlaceApi = restAdapter.create(IGooglePlacesApi.class);
    mGooglePlacesApiResponse googlePlacesObj = iGPlaceApi.getStreams();
} catch (RetrofitError e) {
    serverResponse = e.getMessage();
} finally {
    Log.d("serverResponse:", serverResponse);
}
```

The RetrofitError thrown depending on the failure will contain the exception cause or the status reported by the server.  You can then apply the necessary logic from there.

For more general purposes error handling you can set an [ErrorHandler](http://square.github.io/retrofit/javadoc/retrofit/ErrorHandler.html) when creating your RestAdapter.  This ErrorHandler will be executed before you catch the RetrofitError in your try/catch.